# heroku: Gemfile.lock is required issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, production

I have the following issue:

I'm trying to deploy my project on heroku but after i run

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following:

```
git push heroku master -f
Counting objects: 524, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (498/498), done.
Writing objects: 100% (524/524), 157.76 KiB, done.
Total 524 (delta 207), reused 62 (delta 2)
-----> Heroku receiving push 
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
!
!     Gemfile.lock is required. Please run "bundle install" locally
!     and commit your Gemfile.lock.
!
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
To git@heroku.com:*****.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:*****.git'
```

I have run `bundle install` and `bundle update` for several times, i tried to delete `Gemfile.lock` from the repository and from my filesystem. But i still get the same message. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

The branch i'm trying to push is cloned from master.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Few things

1. Did you placed Gemfile.lock in git? if yes, is it lock (means updated? - you did  several times just double check)
2. Just do `bundle install` on your local prompt.
3. now place Gemfile.lock

   - `git add .` or you can add only Gemfile.lock with this `git add Gemfile.lock`
   - git commit -m "commit message here"
   - git push

Now do `git push heroku` it should work.

Comment: Ok, First remove Gemfile.lock from Heroku and github and place new one, Can you come to the chat? - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ we can chat

Answer (score 7):

On your development machine run
 `rm -rf .bundle && bundle install && git add Gemfile.lock && git commit -m "Added Gemfile.lock"`
Then deploy.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your Gemfile.lock is not committed to your repository. Use `git st` and ensure that the Gemfile.lock is committed; check your .gitignore file to make sure that you're not accidentally ignoring it.

Comment: i've checked it, this file is in my commit. used `git ls-files` to check this

Answer (score 3):

Check your .gitignore file, if you put Gemfile.lock there, get rid of that line and run this commands:

```
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Added Gemfile.lock"
git push
git push heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you need to push a Gemfile.lock - that's how Heroku knows what versions of gems your application is using. After bundling locally, commit the resultant Gemfile.lock then push the application to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I forgot the `bundle install`

After it and git & Heroku everything went OK 
Don't forget either the `git remote`

after writing your code the sequence would be :

```
bundle install
heroku create
git init
git add *
git remote
git commit -a -m "First init"
git push heroku master
```

I think it's complete

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `/Gemfile.lock` from your .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check your .hgignore file as well and remove the line Gemfile.lock