# Failed to deploy redmine to HEROKU due to Gemfile.lock nonexistence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I had this particular error upon pushing/deploying to Heroku

```
Counting objects: 92259, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19977/19977), done.
Writing objects:  48% (45054/92259), 13.63 MiB | 103 KiB/s    

Writing objects: 100% (92259/92259), 23.82 MiB | 87 KiB/s, done.
Total 92259 (delta 72165), reused 90569 (delta 70774)

-----> Ruby/NoLockfile app detected
 !
 !     Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/NoLockfile app

To git@heroku.com:xiruki-task.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xiruki-task.git'
```

I've tried to remove the Gemfile.lock and bundle install again but no luck.

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Comment: is your Gemfile.lock in your git repo?

Comment: Dont have a git repo. I am directly pushing it to Heroku. Is it not the right way?

Comment: well… have a look at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

In short, yes you need git because that is how you deploy your code to Heroku. Whatever got checked in to your git repo will get pushed to Heroku server.

Also, I didn't mean a remote repo like Github but the local one which I think you should already have otherwise you won't be able to push to heroku in the first place.

Comment: Why do I have (-) response to my question? Hmm anyway thanks for explaining!

Comment: because you very clearly did not read the error message before posting this question.

Comment: If I clearly read and understood it, I won't be posting this question right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [heroku: Gemfile.lock is required issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605863/heroku-gemfile-lock-is-required-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `bundle install` and that will generate your gemfile.lock. Then commit it and deploy to heroku

Comment: I have Gemfile.lock already. Seems like I really forgot to push it in github