# Ruby on Rails Heroku - error deploying project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, heroku

Recently I tried to push my Rails project to git using Heroku, but the wild problem appeard. 
All lines I pasted here: http://pastebin.com/5y09wFCi 
Here I paste lines, which I found most important:

```
$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 98, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (89/89), done.
Writing objects: 100% (98/98), 20.04 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 98 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
.
.
.
   Bundle completed (26.03s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2015-02-07T17:06:17.823271 #1283]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_374afebb598e92eacd894ae2e50e6a4d/public/assets/application-4be62d87c5bb7f3e09992032049b2bd0.js
       rake aborted!
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
.
.
.
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:stark-tor-4197.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stark-tor-4197.git'
```

stark-tor-4197 is my randomly named project.

It may be also important - I read, that Heroku don't work with sqlite3, so I had to make change in my gemfile.
Now part about database looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/EKjFzKDh

```
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago I also had this problem where the following happened:

```
git push github master
To git@github.com:Joey-project/project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Joey-project/project.git'
```

I've been told that the most common reason of this happening is because one is trying to push a branch to a remote branch that has been updated in the meantime.

In general one has to use a variation of the following commands:

```
git fetch github; git merge github/master
```

Any chance you already looked at RomanKapitonov's question ([heroku: Gemfile.lock is required issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605863))? I believe it's related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `rake assets:precompile` on your local as it looks like there is some error in your assets i.e. javascript or css files.